# What exactly is the Length of an Array in bash and how to differ '*' and '@'?

Tags: bash, array

I have the following example script and want to know what exactly is the length of an array, are this bytes, characters or what else?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Arrays
# @ vs. *

ape=( "Apple Banana" "Emacs Window" "Panda Bamboo Nature" )
cape=( 'Ping Pong' 'King Kong' 'King Fisher Club' 'Blurb' )
jade=( ally belly cally delly )

echo Expansion with \*
echo ${ape[*]}
echo ${cape[*]}
echo -e "${jade[*]}\n"

echo Expansion with \@
echo ${ape[@]}
echo ${cape[*]}
echo -e "${jade[@]}\n"

echo Elements with \*
echo ${#ape[*]}
echo ${#cape[*]}
echo ${#jade[*]}

echo Elements with \@
echo ${#ape[@]}
echo ${#cape[@]}
echo ${#jade[*]}

echo -e "\nLength"
echo ${#ape}
echo ${#cape}
echo ${#jade}
```

From the man pages I know, that the array expansion differs from `*` to `@` if the word is double-quoted or not, but I cannot see any differences. Why do I have in both cases the same results?

The output is as follows:

```
Expansion with *
Apple Banana Emacs Window Panda Bamboo Nature
Ping Pong King Kong King Fisher Club Blurb
ally belly cally delly

Expansion with @
Apple Banana Emacs Window Panda Bamboo Nature
Ping Pong King Kong King Fisher Club Blurb
ally belly cally delly

Elements with *
3
4
4
Elements with @
3
4
4

Length
12
9
4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the case where it shows that `*` will expand the array to a single string, and `@` expands to individually quoted strings:

```
printf 'string "%s"\n' "${cape[*]}"
```

which generates

```
string "Ping Pong King Kong King Fisher Club Blurb"
```

and

```
printf 'string "%s"\n' "${cape[@]}"
```

which generates

```
string "Ping Pong"
string "King Kong"
string "King Fisher Club"
string "Blurb"
```

Remember that `echo` just concatenates its arguments and prints them, while `printf` will fill out its format string with the arguments and repeat the same format if more arguments are supplied.

Also,

```
for s in "${cape[*]}"; do
    echo "$s"
done
```

generates a single line of output (it only iterates of a single string), while

```
for s in "${cape[@]}"; do
    echo "$s"
done
```

generates one per array element.

---

You always want to use double quotes around the `${array[*]}` and `${array[@]}` expansions, unless you for some reason want to explicitly invoke word splitting and file name globbing.  And you use `*` or `@` depending on whether you need the array elements all together as one string, or individually quoted.

In my experience, one very seldom use `[*]`.

---

When getting the length of an array, it doesn't matter which of `*` or `@` you use.  But if you use neither, you'll get the length in characters of the first element of the array.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that using `${array[@]}` or `${array[*]}` unquoted almost never makes sense.

Comment: In `bash`, like in `ksh` (but contrary to all other shells and languages), `$array` is short for `${array[0]}` as opposed to all the elements, so `${#array}` is the length of the element of indice 0 (not necessarily the first element, again in bash like in ksh and contrary to most if not all other shells and languages, arrays are sparse).

Comment: `${array[*]}` is handy if you want to create a string from the array with a custom separator. Here's one I use all the time. `a=10 b=1 addr=(); for c in {1..5}; do for d in {21..25}; do addr+=("$a.$b.$c.$d"); done; done; aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters "Name=addresses.private-ip-address,Values=[$(IFS=','; echo "${addr[*]}"))]"`. I could have used `printf` but I'm old.

Comment: @Bruce Yes, those kinds of instances is when you'd want to use `[*]`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the different quoting you used in the variable assignments, I believe you've misinterpreted the phrase "if the word is double-quoted or not" to mean "if the array element(s) are double-quoted", while the manual intends "if the word representing the variable being expanded is double-quoted or not".

You are also using `echo` with the variable expansions happening on the same line; you might get clearer results if you use something more configurable, such as `printf` (as [Kusalananda did](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430006/117549)), or as:

```
$ printf -- '->%s<-\n' "${ape[@]}"
->Apple Banana<-
->Emacs Window<-
->Panda Bamboo Nature<-
```

If you could see the intermediate values that printf does, you'd see:

```
printf -- '->%s<-\n' "Apple Banana" "Emacs Window" "Panda Bamboo Nature"
```

As opposed to the unquoted version:

```
$ printf -- '->%s<-\n' ${ape[@]}
->Apple<-
->Banana<-
->Emacs<-
->Window<-
->Panda<-
->Bamboo<-
->Nature<-
```

... where the intermediate values are:

```
printf -- '->%s<-\n' Apple Banana Emacs Window Panda Bamboo Nature
```

... which shows exactly what the elements have been expanded to. In the first case, the variable is quoted, so no further word-splitting happens, and you get the three elements back. In the second case, each of those three elements also undergoes word splitting, so `printf` sees *seven* elements to print.

The "length" of an array is usually the number of elements, which you've generated with the `${#ape[@]}` syntax.  Using `${#ape}` asks bash for the length of the first element:

> Referencing an array variable without a subscript is equivalent to referencing with a subscript of 0

which is why you get those different values.